# How can i center these images on my screen

Tags: html, css

I found this code on google because I didn't know how to make 3 or more images appear in a row, no I am wanting the images to be smaller than the original 33.33% they were for width, I want them to be about 20% in size, however, it doesn't center the row of images and I was curious how or why it won't. code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/4/6/wEVac7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-postion: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/2019-dodge-challenger-srt-hellcat-redeye-review/66601/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3d/2c/50/3d2c50b15c1c31928ad7b556b5295479.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/news/paris-2014-a-plug-in-hybrid-from-lamborghini-yes-sir/59396/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/27/f7/b027f7c377a8ad0333d80c9e935e9e20.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/review-2018-mclaren-570s-spider/64906/" target="_blank"><img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/McLaren-logo-344C083021-seeklogo.com.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: at the .column for the css is where the width is and it was 33.33% making the images cover the entire page because that adds up to 100%, but i want them smaller than that in size but still centered on my page

Comment: first you have unclosed a tags and in css position missing the  i letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend FlexBox here. Depending on what you want, you can use `justify-content: center` or `justify-content: space-between`.

Centered:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/4/6/wEVac7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-postion: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/2019-dodge-challenger-srt-hellcat-redeye-review/66601/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3d/2c/50/3d2c50b15c1c31928ad7b556b5295479.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/news/paris-2014-a-plug-in-hybrid-from-lamborghini-yes-sir/59396/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/27/f7/b027f7c377a8ad0333d80c9e935e9e20.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/review-2018-mclaren-570s-spider/64906/" target="_blank"><img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/McLaren-logo-344C083021-seeklogo.com.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Space-between:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/4/6/wEVac7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-postion: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/2019-dodge-challenger-srt-hellcat-redeye-review/66601/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3d/2c/50/3d2c50b15c1c31928ad7b556b5295479.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/news/paris-2014-a-plug-in-hybrid-from-lamborghini-yes-sir/59396/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/27/f7/b027f7c377a8ad0333d80c9e935e9e20.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/review-2018-mclaren-570s-spider/64906/" target="_blank"><img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/McLaren-logo-344C083021-seeklogo.com.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I made a class called "center" but you can just change it back to column. It centers the images using **margin-left**, **margin right** and finally **display**

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/4/6/wEVac7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-postion: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="center">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/2019-dodge-challenger-srt-hellcat-redeye-review/66601/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3d/2c/50/3d2c50b15c1c31928ad7b556b5295479.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/news/paris-2014-a-plug-in-hybrid-from-lamborghini-yes-sir/59396/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/27/f7/b027f7c377a8ad0333d80c9e935e9e20.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.auto123.com/en/car-reviews/review-2018-mclaren-570s-spider/64906/" target="_blank"><img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/McLaren-logo-344C083021-seeklogo.com.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%"></p>
  </div>
```

You can learn more about centering images [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp)